# Backface in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, hidden

I have managed to get my flipping card to work correctly in FF, Chrome, I haven't tested Opera and IE is being a pain.

The card shows correctly in IE and flips, however when the card is flipped over it is showing the front contents upside down and not the contents of the back of the card.

I've read something about IE 10 not supporting preserve 3d, but to be honest I have no idea what that even is as I've adapted the code I'm using from someones demo.

Can anyone help me to get the back contents of the card to show when it is flipped please?

http://jsfiddle.net/GFVxD/2/

```
  .stage {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000; 
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
    -o-perspective: 1000; 
    perspective: 1000;
}

.flashcard {
  height: 300px;  
  width: 500px; 
  margin: 10% auto;
  border: 1px solid gray; 
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;  
  transition: all 0.3s;               
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition:all 1s linear;
}

.flipped, .back {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); 
}

.front, .back {
  height: 300px;          
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;    
  text-align: center;   
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
-o-backface-visibility:hidden;
backface-visibility:hidden; 
}
.front p {  
margin-top: 10%;         
font-size: 1.5em;  
line-height: 30px;}

.back p {  

margin-top: 10%;         
font-size: 1em;  
line-height: 30px;}

.qanswer p {    
font-size:4px;}
```

Comment: Sadly I think this is a bug in IE right now. Hopefully it will be fixed in a few months. It drives me crazy too.

Comment: I confirm this seem to be a bug, I have exactly the same issue for now...

Comment: Well it is really annoying because I want to go live with my website but cant because of this!!